# Turbo Tax Reporting Income with No 1099

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax

I use Turbo Tax for Business and I have already entered all the income I received from 1099 MISC.

But I do have other income which does not provided any 1099. This includes Google Adsense, Apple Apps and some other side projects I did.

Where do I enter that income. I found a section called "General Business Income" in the business section. This section allows you enter the name of the income in textfield and how much you earn.

Is that where I should be entering the income?

Comment: Adsense and Apple Apps should both be able to provide you with relevant tax documents.

Comment: You should contact Apple and Google. They definitely do issue 1099's as long as you've hit the $600 threshold with each company.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can add it there. You can also add it to the "[gross receipt line](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2281496-how-can-i-report-income-with-no-1099)". Note that you do not have to list where it came from, just the total.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just list where it came from for my own reference. Thanks!